# Get QVariantMap from QVariant(QVariantList)

Tags: c++, qt

I have QVariant(QVariantList), in that some QVariantMap. How can I pull QVariantMap from QVariantList?

[image: Structure of QVariant]

Comment: `QVariantMap myMap = varList.toList()[1].toMap();`

Comment: What means "pull QVariantMap"? Do you need to read the content of `QVariantMap` elements?

Comment: Yes, I do. I need to get int64_t value from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `QVariant` is called `my_variant`, you can extract its content the following way:

```
// Get the list (since the underlying type of my_variant is QVariantList)
QVariantList va_list = my_variant.toList();

for(int i = 0; i < va_list.size(); ++i)
{
    // Get the map
    QVariantMap va_map = va_list[i].toMap();

    for(auto cit = va_map.cbegin(); cit != va_map.cend(); ++cit)
    {
        // Extract the value you desired
        int64_t my_val = cit.value().toLongLong();

        // Here we go, do whatever you want with the extracted value :)
    }
}
```